# Do all floating numeric values use Double instead of Float in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, math, .net-3.5

Is it the case with WPF since it's written from scratch, thus doesn't need to be like WinForms?

Just like C# Math uses Double by default, right?

I wanted to ask this after seeing classes like LinearDoubleKeyFrame, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any "default" type used by the math classes.  You can use either float or double, its your choice.  Most of the methods are overloaded, so it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: You are right, what I meant to say was, if you do literal math, like 4*25, C# assumes them Double.

Comment: C# doesn't default that to any particular type.  The types remain the same through the calculation. For example, if you do `4*25` the result is an int.  If you do `4.0*25.0` the result is a double.  If you do `4f*25f`, the result is a float.

Comment: I know I meant to say if you don't use the f suffix, then a floating value is gonna be treated as a double. Also I am wondering in the case of WPF.

Comment: If the floating types that are used in the expression are doubles, then yes they will be treated as doubles.  I'm not very familiar with WPF, but I can't imagine that it would be different.